# Caustics in Path Tracing

Tags: graphics, raytracing

I'm creating a path tracer, and want to render caustics. I know a backwards path tracer is not the most efficient at rendering caustics, but I would like to get at least a noisy version working first before extending it.

I think I'm able to get refractions now, but I see no caustics from the two spherical light sources located on top of and to the left of the spheres in the scene (see image for more details)

image of the output of the path tracer:

[image: image of the output of the path tracer]

I think my refraction code might be wrong since as I understand it if you get refraction right, you should get caustics for free with a path tracer.

The following is the code for computing the refracted ray direction:

```
# reflection direction. 
d_Re = ray_direction - 2*(ray_dir_dot_N)*N

# are we inside or outside the sphere?
out_to_in = ray_dir_dot_N < 0

IOR = material['IOR'] if out_to_in else 1/material['IOR']
nl = N if out_to_in else -N

cos_theta = ray_direction[0]*nl[0]+ray_direction[1]*nl[1]+ray_direction[2]*nl[2]
cos2_phi = 1.0 - IOR**2 * (1-cos_theta**2)

if cos2_phi < 0:
    ray_dir = d_Re
    ray_prob = 1
else:
    d_Tr = (IOR*ray_direction - (IOR*cos_theta + np.sqrt(cos2_phi))*nl)

    d_Tr_dot_N = d_Tr[0]*N[0]+d_Tr[1]*N[1]+d_Tr[2]*N[2]
    c = 1.0 - (-cos_theta if out_to_in else d_Tr_dot_N)
    Re = schlick(IOR, c)

    p_Re = 0.25 + 0.5 * Re

    if np.random.rand() < p_Re:
        ray_dir = d_Re
        ray_prob = Re/p_Re
    else:
        Tr = 1.0 - Re
        ray_dir = d_Tr
        ray_prob = Tr/(1-p_Re)
```

Does anybody have any ideas for what might be wrong?

Comment: That's a lot of code just to get a vector. Check out my code in this question: https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/13681/vulkan-backward-only-path-tracer-with-caustics

Comment: So, basically, to get caustics, you must not always use a random direction, but rather use a refracted ray if transparent. If reflective, then use the reflect vector. Gotta do both? Flip a pseudorandom coin.